# nginx with high traffic socket.io running on docker

Tags: docker, nginx, socket.io

So I am building a web application for university which has a very high tick rate (clients recieving data from node server above 30 times per second via socketio). This works well in docker. Now I installed nginx, configured it and everything works well (no exposed ports, socket still running etc.) **but** now nginx logs in the docker terminal every single socket connection from every single client (at two clients well above 60 logs per second) and I think this also leads to performance issues and causes small lag to the clients. I did not find any solutions in their docs.

Comment: You can in your Nginx config just write: access_log off; and you will turn off access log, either for the entire server or for a specific location.

Comment: @opentokix thanks, that helped a lot!